# mongodb php json of find function

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a document that as an _id value, when I search to get all the records and then do

```
    $cursor = $this->apiClass->mdb->cards->find();
    echo json_encode(iterator_to_array($cursor, false),true);
```

I don't get the _id field in my json array. I want this _id so I can do further actions on the record later.

I actually get an empty id : "_id":{}

Comment: Can you share some more code please? How would anyone know the answer with this little information? Please have a look at creating minimum  complete verifiable question http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id is probably a `\MongoId` instance which can not be dumped in the way you expect by `json_encode`. You need to either cast it to `string` manually first or use something more sophisticated than good ol' `json_encode` (like [JMSSerializer](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer) for example).